# how to set the button unusable ,after successful install a apk?

Tags: android

everyone ,i have a peoblem here ,when i install a apk the system wiil show a install Dialog ,one is "open",the other one is "done",how can i set the "open" button unusable
and when user click "done",it will show the activity that i want to show?thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. The buttons you see (open and done) are part of the installer application, which you can't edit or alter.

Comment: but i find there's a apk can makt that